# Reverse AJAX - no error but wrong behavior

Tags: ajax, vb.net

Hello I have a small web app which uses this Reverese AJAX technique: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Reverse-AJAX-technique-in-3883b1e9 (I'm using the VB version)

The main difference in my web app is a message is sent to multiple clients using a loop in the server code. It loops through a recordset and uses a "UserId" field for the RecipientName.

The problem is, the message content isn't always what I expect it to be when I run it. There's no error, but it seems to send the wrong message content. I thought maybe I need DoEvents() in the code to let it process each message in the loop. But this didn't help.

I have looked through all my code several times and I am pretty sure the problem lies in the mentioned loop or the Reverse AJAX service.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code so the problem can be replicated?

Comment: Yes, here is the loop code which seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed this issue. I put the "send message to host" code before the loop instead of after, and this seems to have fixed it. No idea why this worked, it's quite strange.